# How to avoid using multiple threads for multiple clients in a C++11 server program

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I was asked this question in an interview and my answer was to avoid using multiple threads and use a "cooperative multitasking" (single process). I really want to know how should I process efficiently multiple clients in a C++ crossplatform server without having a thread for each client. Do C++11 provide some tools that can be useful in that context ?

Comment: Have a queue of clients and process them one at a time. How to do it efficiently would depend on the task.

Comment: You should look at boost asio.

Comment: I heard about Boost ASIO but I didn't understand how its multithreading works (work pool thread or something like that, is it really starting an OS service ?). If you have some beginner good article explaining how it works internally please give me a link.

Comment: @Aminos, please see my answer, the link to boost.asio brings you to the documentation, containing also rationale, concepts and more.

Comment: Hello! This question would be improved if you had a specific code example which is not returning the results that you expect. That way we can help debug where the issues are and provide more specific help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the way you do this is by processing requests asynchronically, i.e., by call back functions, and then get these callback functions queued, so that they don't conflict.

### Synchronous vs Asynchronous calls

What's the difference between synchronous and asynchronous function calls?

**Synchronous call:** Calls a function and gets it to immediately do its work. The same thread does the call, and the call blocks until the function finishes/returns; hence: Nothing else can be done until it's finshed. This is what you typically do in every normal program.

**Asynchronous call:** Puts a function call on a queue, and then, the function can be called from the same or another thread.

Normally, for client/server applications, you never use synchronous calls to process transferred data. Once you digest this point, you'll understand how multithreading works there, and **everything will become easy**!

### How do asynchronous calls work on a server/client program?

For example, in [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), you can set a function to be called when the [server/client receives data](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html). Basically, what you do is that you tell Boost Library: If my server receives data (say `std::string buffer`), I want you to call this function to process this data.

(notice that the synchronous alternative is that you call, and wait until the server receives something, and the thread just completely blocks until something is received. This isn't convenient at all! Which is why synchornous calls are not a good idea).

### How do I start with asynchronous programming?

Boost ASIO provides the class [`io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html), which is basically the handler of asynchronous calls of ASIO. Here's an example:

```
void handle_async_receive(...) { ... }
void print() {
    std::cout<<"Hello!"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    //some stuff
    io_service.post(&print);                             
    socket.connect(endpoint); //this is synchronous, so it connects and returns after the connection process is finished                    
    socket.async_receive(buffer, &handle_async_receive); 
    io_service.post(&print);                             
    io_service.run(); //this will block until the io_service queue is empty
}
```

All the print calls will not happen when you `post`. You simply put them on a queue, and they'll be executed when you do `run()` the `io_service`.

### What about multithreading?

For multithreading, there's a solution in Boost ASIO that's called [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.htmlv). All you have to do before posting any function to `io_service`, is to "wrap" it with a strand. A strand simply queues function calls even if they're on multiple threads. Hence, it's a non-blocking solution, unlike mutexes.

Answer (score 3):

To really avoid using multiple threads, either yourself or indirectly through a library like Boost.Asio, I would use poll/select/epoll (pick your color) to monitor the server listen socket plus all the client socket(s). By default, your process could sit there without a timeout, waiting for a socket event to occur.
Then it depends if your server process does all the work by itself, then you might need to find a way to split large/long-processing requests in smaller chunks, in order to give other clients a chance/time slot. Then you build a queue of these processing chunks, check non-waiting the sockets, then process a chunk again, until the chunk queue is empty again.
If the heavy work is done e.g. by a database, send the request to the database, check the sockets, check for reply from the DB server etc. until the request was processed completely.

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion is to not do it yourself, unless you really want to do it (i.e. for your knowledge or study).

There are various libraries that should fullfill this task,
[boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is one ot them.